# Android App shows status published but not available to install says preregister instead of install

Tags: google-play

From the documentation it says if a app status is published it should be available to download but for me instead of install option i have pre-register. Ho long should i wait for it to show install.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [help pages for pre-registration are here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9084187). It looks like you may have selected pre-registration by accident when targeting countries.

To get out of this the instructions are in the section "Launch your game from pre-registration"

> - Sign in to your Play Console.
> - Select an app or game that you made available for pre-registration..
> - Click Store presence > Pricing & distribution.
> - In the “Countries” section, click Manage countries.
> - Next to the countries where you want to launch your app or game, select Available.
> - Select Submit update.

If you really ended up here by accident, rather than choosing it as described on that page it is a bug. Please report it to Play Console Support on the Play Console help page.

Comment: I submitted the update as you suggested. Will let you know the result of it as soon as i get some update on the app. Thank you.

Comment: @Gajula Did the button changed from "Pre-register" to "Install". How much time it will take to do so?

Comment: This really helped me a lot (pointed me to the right documentation), thanks.