# How to make my application available for users in play store

Tags: android, google-play

i made an application and uploaded it to production track in play console application is published but as pre registration how to fix this that my users can download ut now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. See meta

Comment: Look at this: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App shows status published but not available to install says preregister instead of install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432160/android-app-shows-status-published-but-not-available-to-install-says-preregister)

Answer (score 0):

The [help pages for pre-registration are here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9084187). It looks like you may have selected pre-registration by accident when targeting countries.

To get out of this the instructions are in the section "Launch your game from pre-registration"

> - Sign in to your Play Console.
> - Select an app or game that you made available for pre-registration..
> - Click Store presence > Pricing & distribution.
> - In the “Countries” section, click Manage countries.
> - Next to the countries where you want to launch your app or game, select Available.
> - Select Submit update.

If you really ended up here by accident, rather than choosing it as described on that page it is a bug. Please report it to Play Console Support on the Play Console help page.